# How many secrets are on each level?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I know that there are a total of 71 secrets in the game, but finishing up my first play through the game I see I've missed some, and I don't know where to even begin to look as I start a 2nd game and go for the Seeker of Secrets achievement.

I'd like to know how many secrets are on each level, so as I play through the game again, I can have a better sense of which ones I might be missing and where I need to focus more effort on searching.

**How many secrets are on each dungeon level?**

Comment: Though I don't know how many there are per level, remember to check the pits for secrets on the level below... they sometimes fall into areas you cn only access by the pits.

Comment: @Holger What! **Now** I find out about that!? Now I'm going to have to go fall in to all the pits!

Comment: Hehe yeah I found out about it on level 3 or so... so tempted to backtrack and check all the pits... but that can take a while... (though only on lvl 4 or 5)

Comment: Suggest you reference the achievement "Seeker of Secrets", since it will add SEO relevance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be a complete list now:

http://www.gamebanshee.com/legendofgrimrock/secrets/secrets_level1.php

It has levels 1-10 and lvl 13.

The number of secrets seem to vary, but here are the numbers:

- Level  1:  3
- Level  2:  6
- Level  3:  8
- Level  4:  8
- Level  5:  7
- Level  6: 12
- Level  7:  9
- Level  8:  6
- Level  9:  4
- Level 10:  6
- Level 13:  2

This gives 71.

That should be all the secrets found, if I've written the numbers correct. GameBanshee now states it has 70 of 71 secrets, but I've gotten it as 71.

The secrets are counted such that if there is a secret on level 4 that can only be reached by dropping in a pit from level 3, it is counted as a level 3 secret, not a level 4 secret.

Comment: Well it was just to try to come with a range (in a very unelegant way). It was something I wrote before deciding to type out the number from that page. I'll try to rectify it, even though the ranges do fit (the lowest is 2 and highest is 11, with most concentrated around the 6-8 range.

Comment: Nevermind, you're fine. I just got confused by the wording.

Comment: There are 71 Secrets to find in total, according to ingame statistics. Just sayin :).

Comment: @scorcher24 I know, it's also written in the question. But so far only 62 have been found on that page.

Comment: The Grimrock Hints forum on their website has a thread that's up to 70/71 secrets, that might be helpful.

Comment: @Tacroy could you add a link to it, I haven't found the thread (but haven't looked that much, as I'm at work). Thanks

Comment: If I have to, say, fall down a pit on level 3 to find a secret at the bottom of the pit, is that secret considered to be on level 3 or level 4?

Comment: @Sterno I would have presumed it to be on the level it is found on. But it seems they are "tried" to the levels you drop down from (as you have to be on that level to get to it). Eg: http://www.gamebanshee.com/legendofgrimrock/secrets/secrets_level3.php secret 3

Comment: @Holger That was my impression from reading it too, but I wanted to get verification. I edited your answer to add that and accepted it.